# Creating a map using python

Tags: python, dataframe, geospatial

I have created a geodataframe(as shown below) and would like to know if I can create a map from the points with their attributes, or is that a job for GIS??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download a TopoJSO, GeoJSON, or Shapefile file to build a functional map. The geo-locations or coordinates, latitude, and longitude will only help you plot a point on the map.

**Here is a working sample:** https://rosenfelder.ai/create-maps-with-python/

**Below are links to Shape and JSON files**

1. https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/countries
2. https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0da030d7979c46088b1bcd1e8225cd90
3. https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html

You are on the right track, but more work will be needed.